# Do Images created in memory block page rendering / performance

Tags: javascript, image, dom

Would an image request made in memory impede page performance/rendering.

```
    myImage=new Image();
    myImage.src = "http://somesite.com/images/smallImage.gif?par1=val1&par2=val2";
```

smallImage.gif is a 1x1 pixel transparent gif.  It is only used to push data to the server in the image source query string and serves no other purpose on the page.  Would a delay in response from the server cause an issue with page performance since it only exists in memory and is not part of the html content?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript image object is the same than an `<img />` tag.

1. the image is requested over the network, so it will consume bandwidth that can slow down loading time of other elements it all depends on the size of the image. Of course this will only happen if the JS code loading the image occurs while the page is not fully rendered.
2. the javascript image object loads asynchronously (image `onload` event handler is called async) so it will not block the execution of the rest of your javascript code.
3. Browsers are rendering the DOM first and then the medias. So even if your image is huge and slow to load the rest of the DOM will display before.

As you can see in the snippet below, the div after the img tag is rendered before the image finishes to load.

```html
<div>Hello </div>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Fronalpstock_big.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto; object-fit:contain;" />
<div>World !</div>
```